# CSS: How to show hidden part?

Tags: css

I'm not much in CSS and wondering how to show hidden part in the screenshot below:

[image]

The whole CSS looks as following:

```
<style lang="stylus" scoped>
.draw-buttons-container .panel-body
  height 46px
.edit-coordinates
  position absolute
  right 9px
  bottom 48px
  z-index: 1
  .panel
    margin-bottom 0px
  .panel-body
    padding 5px
.load-geometry-file
  position absolute
  right 9px
  bottom 108px
  z-index: 1
  width 30%
  min-width 300px
  max-width 500px
  .panel
    margin-bottom 0px
  .panel-body
    padding 5px
.layout
  right 9px
  z-index: 1
  margin-right 5px
  margin-top 0
  bottom 0
  .panel
    margin-bottom 5px
    margin-right 0px
  .panel-body
    padding 5px
  button
    margin-right 2px
.coordinates-panel
  height 243px
.material-icon
  font-family 'Material Icons'
  font-size 11px
  font-weight normal
  font-style normal
</style>
```

Comment: set background-color and increase z-index

Comment: It doesn't help.

Comment: I've found the solution in another piece of CSS code. Thank you all. Please, delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

higher the z-index value up to a higher value as your map like 99999

```
z-index: 99999
```

Comment: It doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try upping the z-index

`z-index: 100`

Comment: It doesn't help.

Comment: try z-index: 100 !important;  if that doesnt work lmk there may be one other thing you could try

Comment: The same thing.

Comment: try changing position to relative, absolute position can prevent z-index from working.